# Convert a bit array to a struct array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Here's what I've got currently. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it or, better yet, a way to cast my array to the required type without iterating over the entire structure.

My input is a `CFDataRef` containing pixel data. I'd like to convert it to an array of Pixels.

```
struct Pixel {
    let r: UInt8
    let g: UInt8
    let b: UInt8
    let a: UInt8
}

var intArray = [UInt8](count: CFDataGetLength(data), repeatedValue: 0)
let dataRange = CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(data))
CFDataGetBytes(data, dataRange, &intArray)

var pixelArray : [Pixel] = []
for var i = 0; i < intArray.count; i += 4 {
    let p = Pixel(r: intArray[i], g: intArray[i+1], b: intArray[i+2], a: intArray[i+3])
    pixelArray.append(p)
}
```

Comment: You might look at UnsafeBufferPointer<Pixel> overlaid on intArray.  Details up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GoZoner's hint, I found [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/243161?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple DevForums. Below is my final, working, solution.

```
struct Pixel {
    let r: UInt8
    let g: UInt8
    let b: UInt8
    let a: UInt8
}

let data: CFData! = ...
let width: Int = ...
let height: Int = ...

let pixelPtr = UnsafePointer<Pixel>(CFDataGetBytePtr(data))
let pixelBuf = UnsafeBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: pixelPtr, count:width*height)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess for Swift 3 and after, the solution needs to be updated as follows:

```
let pixelPtr0 = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(CFDataGetBytePtr(data))
let pixelPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(pixelPtr0)?.bindMemory(to: Pixel.self, capacity: 1)
let pixelBuf = UnsafeBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: pixelPtr, count:width*height)
```

It works for me.